# How To get row and column clicked in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

How I can get row and column clicked in `MouseUp` event?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx) method to recursively search for the DataGridCell that contains the source of the MouseUp event.

From there you can get the column and row